# SMART - how much I should worry about SSD drive failing in past on "Cumulative Corrected ECC Error Count"?

Tags: ssd, smart

[image]

It is in my current self-test report, but I see it was present already in first self-test report at 8960 hours

latest self test, at 18 367 hours:

`sudo smartctl -t offline /dev/sda` offline test:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-167-lowlatency] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron BX/MX1/2/3/500, M5/600, 1100 SSDs
Device Model:     Micron 1100 SATA 512GB
Serial Number:    17101632DAC7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 11632dac7
Firmware Version: M0DL003
User Capacity:    512 110 190 592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Dec  7 11:26:17 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 1076) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   6) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    18368
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       PO--CK   100   100   001    -    4554
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--CK   077   077   010    -    359
187 Reported_Uncorrect      PO--CK   100   100   001    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   053   022   000    -    47 (Min/Max 8/78)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
238 Unknown_Attribute       ----CK   077   077   000    -    23
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    2477
195 Cumulativ_Corrected_ECC POSR-K   100   000   050    Past 0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      PO--CK   100   100   000    -    123854949938
242 Total_LBAs_Read         PO--CK   100   100   000    -    163778821388
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--CK   100   100   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O     51  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O  16383  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x13       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Send and Receive log
0x24       GPL     R/O   8000  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x25       GPL     R/O   8000  Saved Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0       GPL     VS   35328  Device vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS       3  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa3       GPL     VS   13824  Device vendor specific log
0xa4       GPL     VS     354  Device vendor specific log
0xa4       SL      VS      98  Device vendor specific log
0xa5       GPL     VS    8000  Device vendor specific log
0xa5       SL      VS      64  Device vendor specific log
0xa6       GPL     VS    8000  Device vendor specific log
0xa6       SL      VS      64  Device vendor specific log
0xa7-0xdf  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (16383 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Offline             Completed without error       00%     18367         -
# 2  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     17722         -
# 3  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     16419         -
# 4  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     13127         -
# 5  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     12548         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     12417         -
# 7  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     12343         -
# 8  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11980         -
# 9  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11771         -
#10  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11654         -
#11  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11527         -
#12  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11298         -
#13  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11137         -
#14  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11067         -
#15  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     11027         -
#16  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9238         -
#17  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9201         -
#18  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9064         -
#19  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      8960         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed [00% left] (1000215216-1000280751)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       1 (0x0001)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    47 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     23/64 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:      8/78 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/70 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -5/75 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    478 (463)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
 464    2023-12-07 03:29    46  ***************************
 465    2023-12-07 03:30    57  **************************************
 466    2023-12-07 03:31    52  *********************************
 467    2023-12-07 03:32    49  ******************************
 468    2023-12-07 03:33    48  *****************************
 469    2023-12-07 03:34    47  ****************************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ****************************
 473    2023-12-07 03:38    47  ****************************
 474    2023-12-07 03:39    46  ***************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ***************************
 477    2023-12-07 03:42    46  ***************************
   0    2023-12-07 03:43    45  **************************
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  **************************
   6    2023-12-07 03:49    45  **************************
   7    2023-12-07 03:50    44  *************************
   8    2023-12-07 03:51    45  **************************
 ...    ..(  8 skipped).    ..  **************************
  17    2023-12-07 04:00    45  **************************
  18    2023-12-07 04:01    46  ***************************
  19    2023-12-07 04:02    48  *****************************
  20    2023-12-07 04:03    48  *****************************
  21    2023-12-07 04:04    47  ****************************
  22    2023-12-07 04:05    48  *****************************
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  *****************************
  28    2023-12-07 04:11    48  *****************************
  29    2023-12-07 04:12    49  ******************************
  30    2023-12-07 04:13    49  ******************************
  31    2023-12-07 04:14    50  *******************************
  32    2023-12-07 04:15    49  ******************************
  33    2023-12-07 04:16    48  *****************************
  34    2023-12-07 04:17    48  *****************************
  35    2023-12-07 04:18    49  ******************************
  36    2023-12-07 04:19    49  ******************************
  37    2023-12-07 04:20    48  *****************************
  38    2023-12-07 04:21    49  ******************************
  39    2023-12-07 04:22    51  ********************************
  40    2023-12-07 04:23    51  ********************************
  41    2023-12-07 04:24    50  *******************************
  42    2023-12-07 04:25    49  ******************************
  43    2023-12-07 04:26    50  *******************************
  44    2023-12-07 04:27    48  *****************************
  45    2023-12-07 04:28    47  ****************************
  46    2023-12-07 04:29    47  ****************************
  47    2023-12-07 04:30    49  ******************************
  48    2023-12-07 04:31    50  *******************************
  49    2023-12-07 04:32    50  *******************************
  50    2023-12-07 04:33    50  *******************************
  51    2023-12-07 04:34    51  ********************************
  52    2023-12-07 04:35    51  ********************************
  53    2023-12-07 04:36    51  ********************************
  54    2023-12-07 04:37    52  *********************************
  55    2023-12-07 04:38    51  ********************************
  56    2023-12-07 04:39    52  *********************************
  57    2023-12-07 04:40    51  ********************************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ********************************
  62    2023-12-07 04:45    51  ********************************
  63    2023-12-07 04:46    49  ******************************
  64    2023-12-07 04:47    50  *******************************
  65    2023-12-07 04:48    49  ******************************
  66    2023-12-07 04:49    50  *******************************
  67    2023-12-07 04:50    51  ********************************
  68    2023-12-07 04:51    50  *******************************
  69    2023-12-07 04:52    51  ********************************
  70    2023-12-07 04:53    51  ********************************
  71    2023-12-07 04:54    51  ********************************
  72    2023-12-07 04:55    49  ******************************
  73    2023-12-07 04:56    50  *******************************
  74    2023-12-07 04:57    49  ******************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ******************************
  77    2023-12-07 05:00    49  ******************************
  78    2023-12-07 05:01    50  *******************************
  79    2023-12-07 05:02    49  ******************************
  80    2023-12-07 05:03    50  *******************************
  81    2023-12-07 05:04     ?  -
  82    2023-12-07 05:05    62  ***************************************+
  83    2023-12-07 05:06    59  ****************************************
  84    2023-12-07 05:07    56  *************************************
  85    2023-12-07 05:08    56  *************************************
  86    2023-12-07 05:09    53  **********************************
  87    2023-12-07 05:10    52  *********************************
  88    2023-12-07 05:11    53  **********************************
  89    2023-12-07 05:12    53  **********************************
  90    2023-12-07 05:13    51  ********************************
  91    2023-12-07 05:14    51  ********************************
  92    2023-12-07 05:15    52  *********************************
  93    2023-12-07 05:16    51  ********************************
  94    2023-12-07 05:17    51  ********************************
  95    2023-12-07 05:18    51  ********************************
  96    2023-12-07 05:19    50  *******************************
  97    2023-12-07 05:20    51  ********************************
  98    2023-12-07 05:21    50  *******************************
  99    2023-12-07 05:22    50  *******************************
 100    2023-12-07 05:23    50  *******************************
 101    2023-12-07 05:24    51  ********************************
 102    2023-12-07 05:25    51  ********************************
 103    2023-12-07 05:26    50  *******************************
 104    2023-12-07 05:27    50  *******************************
 105    2023-12-07 05:28    50  *******************************
 106    2023-12-07 05:29    52  *********************************
 107    2023-12-07 05:30    51  ********************************
 108    2023-12-07 05:31    51  ********************************
 109    2023-12-07 05:32    51  ********************************
 110    2023-12-07 05:33    50  *******************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *******************************
 113    2023-12-07 05:36    50  *******************************
 114    2023-12-07 05:37    49  ******************************
 115    2023-12-07 05:38    50  *******************************
 116    2023-12-07 05:39    50  *******************************
 117    2023-12-07 05:40    50  *******************************
 118    2023-12-07 05:41    51  ********************************
 119    2023-12-07 05:42    49  ******************************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ******************************
 123    2023-12-07 05:46    49  ******************************
 124    2023-12-07 05:47    50  *******************************
 125    2023-12-07 05:48    51  ********************************
 126    2023-12-07 05:49    50  *******************************
 127    2023-12-07 05:50    50  *******************************
 128    2023-12-07 05:51    51  ********************************
 129    2023-12-07 05:52    51  ********************************
 130    2023-12-07 05:53    50  *******************************
 131    2023-12-07 05:54    50  *******************************
 132    2023-12-07 05:55    51  ********************************
 133    2023-12-07 05:56    51  ********************************
 134    2023-12-07 05:57    51  ********************************
 135    2023-12-07 05:58    50  *******************************
 136    2023-12-07 05:59    50  *******************************
 137    2023-12-07 06:00    50  *******************************
 138    2023-12-07 06:01    51  ********************************
 139    2023-12-07 06:02    52  *********************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *********************************
 142    2023-12-07 06:05    52  *********************************
 143    2023-12-07 06:06    51  ********************************
 144    2023-12-07 06:07    52  *********************************
 145    2023-12-07 06:08    52  *********************************
 146    2023-12-07 06:09    52  *********************************
 147    2023-12-07 06:10    51  ********************************
 148    2023-12-07 06:11    50  *******************************
 149    2023-12-07 06:12    51  ********************************
 150    2023-12-07 06:13    50  *******************************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  *******************************
 155    2023-12-07 06:18    50  *******************************
 156    2023-12-07 06:19    51  ********************************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ********************************
 160    2023-12-07 06:23    51  ********************************
 161    2023-12-07 06:24    52  *********************************
 162    2023-12-07 06:25    51  ********************************
 163    2023-12-07 06:26    52  *********************************
 164    2023-12-07 06:27    51  ********************************
 165    2023-12-07 06:28    50  *******************************
 166    2023-12-07 06:29    49  ******************************
 167    2023-12-07 06:30    49  ******************************
 168    2023-12-07 06:31    49  ******************************
 169    2023-12-07 06:32    50  *******************************
 170    2023-12-07 06:33    50  *******************************
 171    2023-12-07 06:34    49  ******************************
 172    2023-12-07 06:35    49  ******************************
 173    2023-12-07 06:36    48  *****************************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  *****************************
 178    2023-12-07 06:41    48  *****************************
 179    2023-12-07 06:42     ?  -
 180    2023-12-07 06:43     ?  -
 181    2023-12-07 06:44    31  ************
 182    2023-12-07 06:45    32  *************
 183    2023-12-07 06:46    33  **************
 184    2023-12-07 06:47    33  **************
 185    2023-12-07 06:48    34  ***************
 186    2023-12-07 06:49    41  **********************
 187    2023-12-07 06:50    39  ********************
 188    2023-12-07 06:51    40  *********************
 189    2023-12-07 06:52    37  ******************
 190    2023-12-07 06:53    36  *****************
 191    2023-12-07 06:54    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ******************
 195    2023-12-07 06:58    37  ******************
 196    2023-12-07 06:59    38  *******************
 197    2023-12-07 07:00    39  ********************
 198    2023-12-07 07:01    42  ***********************
 199    2023-12-07 07:02    41  **********************
 200    2023-12-07 07:03    41  **********************
 201    2023-12-07 07:04    42  ***********************
 202    2023-12-07 07:05    41  **********************
 203    2023-12-07 07:06    42  ***********************
 204    2023-12-07 07:07    43  ************************
 205    2023-12-07 07:08    44  *************************
 206    2023-12-07 07:09    42  ***********************
 207    2023-12-07 07:10    43  ************************
 208    2023-12-07 07:11    45  **************************
 209    2023-12-07 07:12    46  ***************************
 210    2023-12-07 07:13    47  ****************************
 211    2023-12-07 07:14    47  ****************************
 212    2023-12-07 07:15    47  ****************************
 213    2023-12-07 07:16    48  *****************************
 214    2023-12-07 07:17    48  *****************************
 215    2023-12-07 07:18    49  ******************************
 216    2023-12-07 07:19    48  *****************************
 217    2023-12-07 07:20    48  *****************************
 218    2023-12-07 07:21    48  *****************************
 219    2023-12-07 07:22    47  ****************************
 220    2023-12-07 07:23    47  ****************************
 221    2023-12-07 07:24    49  ******************************
 222    2023-12-07 07:25    49  ******************************
 223    2023-12-07 07:26    49  ******************************
 224    2023-12-07 07:27    46  ***************************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ***************************
 229    2023-12-07 07:32    46  ***************************
 230    2023-12-07 07:33    48  *****************************
 231    2023-12-07 07:34    47  ****************************
 232    2023-12-07 07:35    48  *****************************
 233    2023-12-07 07:36    48  *****************************
 234    2023-12-07 07:37    47  ****************************
 235    2023-12-07 07:38    48  *****************************
 236    2023-12-07 07:39    48  *****************************
 237    2023-12-07 07:40    49  ******************************
 238    2023-12-07 07:41    49  ******************************
 239    2023-12-07 07:42    51  ********************************
 240    2023-12-07 07:43    60  ***************************************+
 241    2023-12-07 07:44    55  ************************************
 242    2023-12-07 07:45    50  *******************************
 243    2023-12-07 07:46    48  *****************************
 244    2023-12-07 07:47    48  *****************************
 245    2023-12-07 07:48    49  ******************************
 246    2023-12-07 07:49    50  *******************************
 247    2023-12-07 07:50    49  ******************************
 248    2023-12-07 07:51    48  *****************************
 249    2023-12-07 07:52    48  *****************************
 250    2023-12-07 07:53    48  *****************************
 251    2023-12-07 07:54    49  ******************************
 252    2023-12-07 07:55    49  ******************************
 253    2023-12-07 07:56    49  ******************************
 254    2023-12-07 07:57    50  *******************************
 255    2023-12-07 07:58    49  ******************************
 256    2023-12-07 07:59    49  ******************************
 257    2023-12-07 08:00    49  ******************************
 258    2023-12-07 08:01    50  *******************************
 259    2023-12-07 08:02    49  ******************************
 260    2023-12-07 08:03    49  ******************************
 261    2023-12-07 08:04    50  *******************************
 262    2023-12-07 08:05    51  ********************************
 263    2023-12-07 08:06    50  *******************************
 264    2023-12-07 08:07    50  *******************************
 265    2023-12-07 08:08    49  ******************************
 266    2023-12-07 08:09    49  ******************************
 267    2023-12-07 08:10    49  ******************************
 268    2023-12-07 08:11    50  *******************************
 269    2023-12-07 08:12    50  *******************************
 270    2023-12-07 08:13    49  ******************************
 271    2023-12-07 08:14    50  *******************************
 272    2023-12-07 08:15    50  *******************************
 273    2023-12-07 08:16    49  ******************************
 274    2023-12-07 08:17    50  *******************************
 275    2023-12-07 08:18    51  ********************************
 276    2023-12-07 08:19    51  ********************************
 277    2023-12-07 08:20    50  *******************************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  *******************************
 280    2023-12-07 08:23    50  *******************************
 281    2023-12-07 08:24    51  ********************************
 282    2023-12-07 08:25    50  *******************************
 283    2023-12-07 08:26    50  *******************************
 284    2023-12-07 08:27    49  ******************************
 285    2023-12-07 08:28    50  *******************************
 286    2023-12-07 08:29    49  ******************************
 287    2023-12-07 08:30    50  *******************************
 288    2023-12-07 08:31    49  ******************************
 289    2023-12-07 08:32    49  ******************************
 290    2023-12-07 08:33    48  *****************************
 291    2023-12-07 08:34    47  ****************************
 292    2023-12-07 08:35    48  *****************************
 293    2023-12-07 08:36    50  *******************************
 294    2023-12-07 08:37    48  *****************************
 295    2023-12-07 08:38    49  ******************************
 296    2023-12-07 08:39    50  *******************************
 297    2023-12-07 08:40    50  *******************************
 298    2023-12-07 08:41    50  *******************************
 299    2023-12-07 08:42    49  ******************************
 300    2023-12-07 08:43    50  *******************************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  *******************************
 304    2023-12-07 08:47    50  *******************************
 305    2023-12-07 08:48    51  ********************************
 306    2023-12-07 08:49    51  ********************************

[Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 34477.]


SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4            4554  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4           18368  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6    123854949938  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6      5638961181  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6    163778821388  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6      2626778074  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4            4744  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              47  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              47  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1              47  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              78  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1               8  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              55  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              35  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1              48  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1              39  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4              50  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              70  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4           13700  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4             286  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1              23  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  4            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x000a  4            3  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
```

From what I see older SMART test outputs are unavailable and I have not saved any :( At least I saved this one.

Comment: "Statistics" tab is complaining that I cooked my SSD for 50 minutes in temperature above 70 (max reached was 78).

Answer (score 1):

Per Micron you can ignore it. In various documents they [state](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/solid-state-storage/tnfd21_m500-mu02_smart_attributes.pdf): "This attribute provides data that is tracked by Micron engineering. It is not indicative of
SSD wear or of impending failure." and [also](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/Documents/Products/Technical%20Note/Solid%20State%20Storage/tnfd14_p400m_SMART_firmware_0100_0200_0225.pdf) "The threshold for this attribute is set to 0, meaning that it never causes a SMART threshold trip". For 1100 document does not list attribute 195 but I assume it will not be different for this model.

Answer (score 1):

The "in the past" indication normally means that this attribute has
shown failure in the past, but that this condition no longer exists.

It is used by Micron to show that the device has been through conditions
that would void warranty or show abuse, but is more to be found
on parameters like the temperature, which means that the disk has
over-heated.

For "Cumulative Corrected ECC Error Count" there is no way that an
ECC error has simply disappeared, so this indication doesn't make sense.

As this attribute doesn't seem to be much used or be much documented
by Micron, I would chalk this to an undocumented usage of the attribute
in a way that is mishandled by the SMART display software.

All the parameters of your disk are otherwise perfect, so you have no
reason to fear a disk failure.